# Getting error while unpacking my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I was trying my hands on local chrome extension and while unpacking that extension i got an error
`Error at key 'content_scripts'. Parsing array failed at index 0: 'js': expected list, got string Could not load manifest.`

following is my "manifest.json" code:

```
{
    "name": "greeting",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "action": {
        "default_title":"greeting",
        "default_popup": "popup.html" 
    },
    "content_scripts":[{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js":"./content.js"
    }],
    "permissions":["tabs"]
}
```

I have an understanding that this error is related to "content_scripts" array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array in `js`:

```
    "content_scripts":[{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["./content.js"]
    }],
```